# I see a blank page when I go to edit option in my custom module. Instead, I should get a form where I could edit the data

Tags: magento-1.7, module, custom, product-edit

I created a custom module for seller management in magento 1.7.0.2.
In the module, the grid for data display is showing fine but when I click the edit button, it redirects fine but shows a blank page. It should show a page similar to the one which comes up when we edit a product. How can I solve this ?

[image: My custom module]
This is my custom module.

[image: This is what I get when I click on the edit option]This is the blank page.

Instead of the blank page, I want a page similar to the product edit page.

### Config.xml

0.1.0    
        
    
    
        
            
                standard
                
                    Mage_ManageSellers
                    managesellers

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mage_managesellers>
                <file>managesellers.xml</file>
            </mage_managesellers>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <managesellers>
            <class>Mage_ManageSellers_Block</class>
        </managesellers>


    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <managesellers>
            <class>Mage_ManageSellers_Helper</class> 
        </managesellers>
    </helpers>


    <models>
     <managesellers>
        <class>Mage_ManageSellers_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>managesellers_mysql4</resourceModel>
     </managesellers>
     <managesellers_mysql4>
        <class>Mage_ManageSellers_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
           <managesellers>
              <table>managesellers</table>
           </managesellers>
        </entities>
     </managesellers_mysql4>
  </models>
  <resources>
     <managesellers_setup>
        <setup>
           <managesellers>Mage_ManageSellers</managesellers>
        </setup>
        <connection>
           <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
     </managesellers_setup>
     <managesellers_write>
        <connection>
           <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
     </managesellers_write>
     <managesellers_read>
        <connection>
           <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
     </managesellers_read>
  </resources>

</global>
```

### IndexController.php

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_title($this->__('Manage Sellers'));
    $myblock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('managesellers/adminhtml_managesellers');
    $this->_addContent($myblock);
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function editAction()
{
    $Id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('managesellers_id');
    $model = Mage::getModel('managesellers/managesellers')->load($Id);

    if($model->getId() || $Id == 0) 
    {
        $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) 
        {
            $model->setData($data);
        }
        Mage::register('managesellers_data', $model);

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('managesellers/managesellers');

        $this->_addBreadcrumb(
            Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Seller Manager'),
            Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Seller Manager')
        );

        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    else 
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
            Mage::helper('managesellers')->__('Seller does not exist')
        );
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}

public function newAction() 
{
    $this->_forward('edit');
}
```

### Edit.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'managesellers';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_managesellers';
    $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('managesellers')->__('Save Seller'));
    $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('managesellers')->__('Delete Seller'));
}
public function getHeaderText()
{
    if( Mage::registry('managesellers_data') && Mage::registry('managesellers_data')->getId() ) 
    {
        return Mage::helper('managesellers')->__("Edit Seller '%s'", $this->htmlEscape(Mage::registry('managesellers_data')->getTitle()));
    }
    else 
    {
        return Mage::helper('managesellers')->__('Add Seller');
    }
}
```

### layout file

```
<adminhtml_managesellers_index>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="adminhtml/template" name="root" template="catalog/product/edit.phtml"/>
</reference name="content">
</adminhtml_managesellers_index>
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you add some code to your question? If the footer is shown, it might be that no content is loaded. If there is no footer, please check your error logs. In both cases: add code.

Comment: this means your edit.php file not exists in Block of your module or admin layout xml file is not defined properly.

Comment: Code added @ArjenMiedema
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this link](https://astrio.net/blog/magento-admin-form/) to create new/edit form in Admin of magento. This will surely fix your problem. please go step-by-step.